# UserDefault not being saved when going back to viewcontroller 1 and then back to viewcontroller 2

Tags: ios, swift, save, default, favorites

Okay so I have two view controllers. One view controller loads up all the cells that is on my Plist and the second view controller opens up the cell and shows you the description. For example:
View Controller 1:
Dog
Cat
Mouse

Click on Dog cell it will take you to View Controller 2:
Dog goes Woof.

view controller 1 is written:

```
  ovverride func prepare(for segue: UIStoryBoardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
         let animals: Animals
         if isFiltering() {
            animals = filteredData[indexPath.row]
            }
         else {
            animals = originalData[indexPath.row]
            }
          let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! SecondViewController
          controller.detailedAnimals = animals
          controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
          contrller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
          }
    }
  }
```

this is what i wrote in viewcontroller 2 updated

```
var isFavorite : Bool = false

@IBAction func addToFav(_ sender:UIButton) {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite 
    UpdateButtonAppearance()
    saveData()
    }

 private func UpdateButtonAppearance(){
if isFavorite{
         let image = UIImage(named: "addFav")
         favButton.setImage(image, for: . normal)
         savedData()
         }

    else {
         let image = UIImage(named: "addFavFilled")
        favButton.setImage(image, for: . normal)
         savedData()
         }
 }

 ovveride func viewDidLoad(){
   UpdateButtonAppearance()
   saveData()
 }  

    //updated code
   func getFilePath () -> String {
   var path: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true) as [AnyObject]
       let documentsDirectory: String = path[0] as! String
       let filepath = documentsDirectory.appending("Animals.plist")
       return filepath
   }

func saveData(){
    let myDict : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    myDict["fav"] = NSNumber(booleanLiteral: isFavorite)
    myDict.write(toFile: self.getFilePath(), atomically: true)
}

func getBool(){
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: self.getFilePath()) {
        var myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: self.getFilePath()) as! 
   [String:AnyObject]
        let myBool: Bool = myDict["fav"]!.boolValue
        isFavorite = myBool
    }
```

I saw a tutorial on how to change the bool in the Plist and wrote it this way. The code compiles but I don't think it is changing the bool value. So on my Animals Plist i have a Item 0 type dictionary, first key is called Animal, type is string, value is "dog" and second key is Description, type is string, value is "dog goes woof" and third key is called fav, type is Bool and value is No for now but I am trying to change this value to Yes but it is not working. Also thank you so much for your comment it was easy to follow and easy to understand.

Comment: Perhaps you’ve told your image view to always load with the empty image? You haven't said how your views are arranged, so view controller 2 may be unloading. When it loads back again, it might ignore its `isFavorite` and just use the empty image every time.

Comment: So how do I check if viewcontroller is unloading everytime? and why is it ignoring isFavorite? Another thing is when I go to ViewController 3 from 2 and go back to ViewController 2 the star is still filled. But if I go back to ViewController 1 and then back to 2 the star is empty again.

Comment: Your new code is writing only the "fav" key and value to the plist, discarding the other data. In `saveData`, you make a new dictionary and add a "fav" NSNumber, then write it out. Instead, you'll want to use the plist's existing contents (it appears you've used an array of "animal" dictionaries), and modify those instead (add the "fav" key to e.g. the first item if you're changing the dog). Also, if I may suggest, go back to `UserDefaults`; it's simpler, and this is the sort of thing it was designed to do.

Comment: yea but if i do userdefaults and put isfavorites it puts all animals as favorites like what wonder dog commented below

Comment: Do it like this:

`var animals = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "animals" /* Or whatever you want this to be */) as! [[String : Any]]? ?? [];
        let dogIndex = animals.indices.first { animals[$0]["Animal"] as? String == "dog" /* Or whichever animal you want to favourite/unfavourite */ }!;
        animals[dogIndex]["fav"] = isFavorite;
        UserDefaults.standard.set(animals, forKey: "animals" /* Match the first UserDefaults call */)`

Answer (score 0):

The star is not filled when you go back to the 2nd view controller because you set the images in the `@IBAction func addToFav(_ sender:UIButton)` method. That is when you tap the button.
You should have that part of the code in another method that you also call in `didLoad()`.

2nd View Controller should be something like this:

```
var isFavorite = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isFavorite")

func didLoad() {
     super.didLoad()
     updateButtonAppearance()
}

private updateButtonAppearance() {
     if isFavorite {
         let image = UIImage(named: "addFavFilled")
         button.setImage(image, for: . normal)
     }

     else {
         let image = UIImage(named: "addFav")
         button.setImage(image, for: . normal)
     }
}

@IBAction func addToFav(_ sender:UIButton) {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite
    UserDefaults.standard.set(isFavorite, forKey: "isFavorite")
    updateButtonAppearance()
}
```

Also the code could be improved to not save the variable in UserDefaults in `addToFav` method, but whenever `isFavourite` is changed. Maybe you will later want to change the state of `isFavourite` in another method which will require code duplication.

Also note that you save a value for all pets in UserDefaults under `isFavourite`. That means if you favor one pet, all other pets will be favored and vice versa. Consider replacing the bool value in user defaults with a dictionary that has keys for each pet and booleans as values.

Comment: FYI - you do not need the call to `synchronize`.

Comment: Ty so much wonder dog that comment helped me a lot but like you said it did change all animals to favorites so I made a boolean on the plist but I just cant change the value inside. So I updated my code above. Thanks again